# Ruby - Platform independent way to determine IPs of all network interfaces?

Tags: ruby, interface, networking, ip-address

Is there an easy way in Ruby for me to get a list of the IP addresses for all network interfaces?  It needs to work in Linux/Win/OSX and I'd prefer to not have to parse ifconfig/ipconfig unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of Ruby 2.1, Socket#getifaddrs is available:

```
001:0> require 'socket'
=> true
002:0> Socket.getifaddrs.map { |i| i.addr.ip_address if i.addr.ipv4? }.compact
=> ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.1.121", "192.168.1.181"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think ruby has a standard api for this but under some assumptions this should be fairly reliable across platforms:

```
require 'socket'
Socket::getaddrinfo(Socket.gethostname, 'echo', Socket::AF_INET).map { |x| x[3] }
```

Here we are assuming quite a few things like the machine having a local hostname pointing to the correct ip addresses.  So, this is definitely not completely reliable but it's platform independent and works on the common setups.

Edit: If you decide to get down to parsing ifconfig, consider forking [ruby-ifconfig](http://github.com/aaalex/ruby-ifconfig).  It claims to do that on most non-windows platforms already.

Comment: "_service_ is a service name ("http", "ssh", …), or a port number (80, 22, …)", so :echo => 'echo'

Comment: The hostname requirement kills this for me..  On a machine with 4 interfaces I just get back ["127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1"]

Comment: Ummm...  Is the tool you are writing server side?  Is using snmp an option?