# How can I get the system's IP address(es) AND (their) associated MAC address in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

As per [Ruby - Platform independent way to determine IPs of all network interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452060/ruby-platform-independent-way-to-determine-ips-of-all-network-interfaces/21690422#21690422) we know that "As of Ruby 2.1, Socket#getifaddrs is available", and there is even a code example of how to get the machine's IP using it.

From the [macaddr gem](https://github.com/ahoward/macaddr/blob/master/lib/macaddr.rb), there is some code to find the MAC address, also using Socket#getifaddrs.

However, it's above my head to combine the two.

The desired output is:

```
{name: {physical_address: macaddress, ip_addresses: [ip1, ip2, ip3..]}}
```

Where:

- `name` is each device name (such as 'en0', 'en1', and so-on)
- `macaddress` is the MAC address (such as `00:28:00:43:37:eb`)
- `ip_addresses` is an array that contains all the IP addresses associated with that MAC address

How can we use the tools we have to connect all the pieces together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract interface names from Socket.getifaddrs elements:

```
require 'socket'
Socket.getifaddrs.each { |if_addr| puts if_addr.name }
```

In a similar way you can also get de IP addresses related to the names:

```
require 'socket'
Socket.getifaddrs.each do |if_addr|
  next unless if_addr.addr.ipv4?
  puts "#{if_addr.name} => #{if_addr.addr.ip_address.to_s}"
end
```

And finally more or less the same for the MAC address:

```
require 'socket'
Socket.getifaddrs.each do |if_addr|
  next unless if_addr.addr.pfamily == Socket::PF_LINK
  puts "#{if_addr.name} => #{if_addr.addr.getnameinfo}"
end
```

Note: Some interfaces could not have a MAC address an returns empty arrays

You only have to join it have your hash :)